# C# WPF TextBox call method on text change

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, filtering

so I recently started coding a WPF MVVM program in C# for the first time and got into a bit of a problem. I made a filter TextBox where the user can type in something and it will filter a list according to it. so my XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SearchFilter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

So when a user inputs something it updates the SearchFilter and then I want it to run the LoadList() method. How would I do that without putting any extra call inside the setter of SearchFilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've completly missed something on my side, sorry for that.
This approach should help you.

XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchFilter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Code Behind

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var viewmodel = DataContext as ViewModel1;

  viewmodel.LoadList();
}
```

In my case this is the ViewModel class, you should try using INotifyPropertyChanged as it will update your UI if you change something in the code and you will need it probably in the future anyways. Also this uses SetProperty which makes it just all cleaner and easier

```
public class ViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Title { get; } = "View 1";

  private string _searchFilter;
  public string SearchFilter 
  {
    get { return _searchFilter; }
    set 
    { 
      SetProperty(ref _searchFilter, value);
    }
  }

  public void LoadList()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Value: "+SearchFilter);
    // your stuff you do in LoadList
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
  }
  protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value,
      [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Btw. sry for the past answer, I missed something that I always forget on this specific problem :/

Comment: In your code you call the LoadList method inside the setter of SearchFilter. I was specifically told that I should NOT call it in the setter since this is bad practice. I had it just like that before but my boss rejected it because I called the LoadList method inside the setter. Really appreciate your help but i need a way to call a method outside the setter of SearchFilter

Comment: Well yes it is bad practice thats true but its a good way to start in a hobby project that doesnt scale that much.

For a better solution you can bind the TextChanged event in Code Behind and call the LoadList() method in your ViewModel.

So you add TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" in xaml code (you should get the option to add eventhandler) and in that you call the method of the viewmodel

Comment: I edited the answer for a better solution

Comment: I wrote TextChanged="RefreshSearchFilter" into the textbox and then in my ViewModel i wrote the function public void RefreshSearchFilter() but it gives me an error message on start saying that EntryListView has no definition for "RefreshSearchFilter" and no expanding methods could be found with the first argument being an "EntryListView". I also tried writing RefreshSearchFilter(object sender) but still same problem

Comment: Thats because you need to Bind it to a method in your ViewModel. But as TextChanged is a event you can't do that because its bound to the view (afaik).

You need to make that method in your code behind, thats why you need to call the method separatly. 


Your TextChanged "Method" must be in code Behind unfortunately

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean with "code behind". What is the code behind? is it the code inside the ViewModel?

Comment: The CodeBehind is the code of your View. In your File explorer you should be able to expand the view File or simply make a right click in your XAML Code Editor and select "show code".

Or you just type TextChanged with autocomplete and it will suggest to create a handler by itself. Then it navigates you to the CodeBehind.




Its the file name with xaml.cs ending.

Comment: Oh i didn't even know that there was any code. That actually helped me a lot. Ok so now I wrote TextChanged="RefreshSearchFilter" into the textbox and made the method inside the code behind and it works fine. Now the textbox just loses focus everytime I call RefreshSearchFilter for some reason but I should be able to figure that one out by myself (unless you want to help me out with that as well). Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Sadly I don't have much time since I'm learning for a Machine Learning exam but if you need any help on that I will try to answer you.

The Code Behind is where you would write your code without MVVM. Normally you start there and then move to MVVM so good for you that you start the "right" way in first place :) also sometimes you need it because it wont work in the ViewModel